# Using Google Maps Tile Service with OpenLayers 5

Tags: openlayers, google-maps-api

How to pass Google Maps API key to access tile service using OpenLayers 5.

Some google searches suggested me to set the url of tile layer as

```
http://mt.google.com/vt/lyrs=m&x={x}&y={y}&z={z}
```

Is this a legal way to access Google tile server data directly without an API key?

As per [this forum](https://github.com/kishikawakatsumi/ClassicMap/issues/7), its a violation of Google Maps TOS.

If this is a violation, what should I need to do to meet their TOS.

I need to overlay some WMS data hosted on GeoServer over Google Map.
I can do so using Google Maps tile server, but without using a Google API.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Accessing Google Tile independent from their API in OL3 is possible for paying customer?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/240696/accessing-google-tile-independent-from-their-api-in-ol3-is-possible-for-paying-c)

Comment: No, this is not duplicate. 
[OL3 provides native support for Google Maps](https://github.com/mapgears/ol3-google-maps).

With OL 4  and above, the Google Maps support was removed. Still Google Maps can be used using its Tile Server. For this there is no need of an API key. Some online forum says that 
[its illegal to access Google map data from its tile server directly without an API key is a violation of its TOS](https://github.com/kishikawakatsumi/ClassicMap/issues/7)

So, what can be done to access Google Maps data from its tile server without violating its TOS.

Comment: https://github.com/mapgears/ol3-google-maps is not OpenLayers (the official github repo is http://github.com/openlayers/openlayers) so there is **no** native support and hence, the support was not removed (it didn't exist since OpenLayers 3 first version)

Comment: A key to access Google maps is now mandatory e.g due to TOS changes e.g https://developers.google.com/maps/billing/important-updates Limit to set a key is 16th of July 2018

Comment: Please look in to the [link](http://dev.openlayers.org/examples/google.html).
I don't think it uses mapgears.

Comment: This is OpenLayers 2, outdated, still working but do not evolve so I can confirm my previous statement

Comment: So, OpenLayers 2 provides native support for Google Maps, and why it was removed in later versions? How can I use Google Maps with an API key using latest version of OpenLayers (not mapgear), like it was in v2. I tried mapgear, but zooming functionality is little laggy, not as smooth as OpenLayers 2.
What would be the risks, if I choose OpenLayers 2?

Comment: Yes, it was removed: a pain to maintain + legal concerns. For using Google Maps with an API but no Mapgears like it was in v2: you simply can't (or you can e.g http://bl.ocks.org/ThomasG77/21192c7045ab8f50e22e but the experience is bad). The risk if choosing OpenLayers 2: bad support on mobile + if any issue with OpenLayers 2, don't expect support. My personal advice: don't keep the stance with Google Maps: don't use it. PS: I will not answer more as most answers I've done are already in the duplicated answer and its links.

Comment: Ok... Thanks a lot. I am editing the content of my question as it may mislead that OL3 supports Google Maps API.

Comment: I think this would be a better choice..
[http://openlayers.org/en/v3.0.0/examples/google-map.html](http://openlayers.org/en/v3.0.0/examples/google-map.html)

Comment: Again, no e.g https://github.com/openlayers/openlayers/pull/2711 (my previous sample is an updated version of your link)

Comment: The bad experience noted by @ThomasG77 in http://bl.ocks.org/ThomasG77/21192c7045ab8f50e22e is due to Google's animated zoom.  Until 14 August 2018 that could be eliminated by specifying ?v3.31 or earlier when loading the API and setting animatedZoom:false in the map options.  Unfortunately the earliest API version now available is 3.32 which doesn't support that option, and examples which did work well now also give a bad experience.

Comment: There's a separate question dealing the animated zoom problem and workarounds here: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/115491/how-to-disable-google-map-zooming-animation-effect

Comment: I did a thorough overview of different ways to get Map Tile Server URL [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59003524/2445273).